# Using AC/DC transformer to step down voltage or as antenna balun

Tags: transformer, balun

You can get an AC/DC step-down transformer like this from many electronic items.

[image]

There are two things I want to do with it:

1. Convert 6V or 12V DC to 3V or 4.5V DC, but it's not doing it. With the one I have, the input leads measure 133 ohms, that's nice so the power source doesn't short itself out and catch on fire; the output leads have no resistance. So I connect a 6V battery to the input, and the output leads have zero volts. Am I doing something wrong or how do you do it?
2. Use as a unun or balun for antenna. Popular examples are 1:9, 1:4, etc. made with separate wires wrapped through/around a toroid. Why isn't this done with a transformer? Can it be done, or why not?

Comment: Transformers depend on the changing magnetic field produced by alternating curent to transfer power from the primary winding to the secondary.   They won't work with the direct current from a battery.

Comment: The power supply blocks that come with many products these days are really DC power supplies, although many people call them "transformers".  They actually contain a transformer to step down the voltage, followed by a rectifier and voltage regulator to change the AC from the transformer to DC.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "AC/DC" transformer, or a DC/AC transformer, or a DC/DC transformer. Transformers don't work with DC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to EE.SE.

> 1. Convert 6V or 12V DC to 3V or 4.5V DC, but it's not doing it.

It won't. While it's common for the general public to loosely call a DC power supply a transformer an actual transformer, as you pictured, only works on AC, not DC. It takes in AC and outputs AC.

To take in a DC supply and output a lower DC voltage you require a [buck convertor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter). (You can google that term for explanations with less equations than that Wikipedia article.) You can buy them ready-made; you'll need to know the current requirement of your load to choose a suitable one.

> 2. Use as a unun or balun for antenna. Popular examples are 1:9, 1:4, etc. made with separate wires wrapped through/around a toroid. Why isn't this done with a transformer?

Transformers are only suitable for specific frequency ranges. The pictured transformer is labelled on the top as being suitable for 50 to 60 Hz operation. It is suitable for AC mains/grid supplies but can't be used as a radio [balun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balun). You need a transformer design suited for the radio frequencies you intend to use it for.

A device with wires wrapped round a toroidal core is a transformer design suitable for short wave radio frequencies. This is a common way of making ununs or baluns for HF. (Other types of balun are possible at VHF and higher frequencies.)